# Combine two Macros?

Tags: c++, c

Following macro MY_SIZE_OF_VARIABLE gives sizeof variables 
and MY_SIZE_OF_DATATYPE gives size of inbuilt datatype. I want to combine these two macro in one Macro.

```
#define MY_SIZE_OF_VARIABLE(X) (char *)(&X+1)-(char *)(&X)
#define MY_SIZE_OF_DATATYPE(X) (X*)0 + 1
```

I tried to combine these but i can't do that.

Comment: If using C++ why are you using macros?

Comment: i want to create my own sizeof() function.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? Also why try to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: @EdHeal Must be part of Homework..

Comment: `#define MY_SIZE_OF(X) sizeof(X)`
There you go? When you're done with that, you realize it's silly and thus just do `sizeof( X )` and be done with it. Also, compiler is allowed to insert padding and spacing between elements of a user data type, so no matter what you do you have to ask the compiler by using `sizeof`. For "built in" types, the sizes are implementation-defined but specified not to go below a certain minimum size, so again you have to ask the compiler.

Comment: Yeah... what do you have there that `sizeof` doesn't provide?

Comment: @SwanandPurankar - The teacher must be very bored

Comment: @ThePhd i want to implement my own sizeof().

Comment: @YogeshKhedkar Well, stop trying to implement your own sizeof(). Unless you're writing a compiler (and you'd already have the information to figure this out), there's no reason to write your own sizeof. You're literally wasting your time. Whole buckets of it.

Comment: @ThePhD Don't you feel that implementing this might cause somebody to stop and think and learn about pointer arithmetic? I for one enjoy the way this is done, even though I know that sizeof already exists. At least don't take the fun away from others.

Comment: Both macros are missing a pair of parentheses around the whole replacement expression.

Comment: @NiklasB. There are better ways to learn the atrocity that is pointer arithmetic.

Comment: @NiklasB. No, because there's probably better ways to learn about pointer arithmetic. He's also not asking about pointer arithmetic, he was asking about essentially using an `if` statement based on what gets put into a macro (a type, or a declared variable). Notwithstanding that I don't think that's possible, the reason for asking about it is a bad one: this is an XY problem.

Comment: Also, [nothing about this correct implementation is fun or necessary to deal with](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f78296f7f9f54157). (I.E. this macro does not deal with overloaded operator& on data types, though he did specify "built in" datatypes, and not user data types).

Comment: @Rapptz sure, but that doesn't mean this task is useless, an utter waste of time or that the teacher is incompetent or bored. WTF this platform sometimes is just much too elite.

Comment: Q. "How do I solve my problem?" A. "Don't solve your problem!"

Comment: @ThePhD: point is that it's obvious that OP is not trying to reimplement sizeof because they don't know it already exists but for some other reason, be it for homework, fun or just 'cause they feel like it for love's sake. There is just no point in arguing about whether it's sensible. The question as such is legitimate, even if it doesn't allow for a satisfying or elegant answer.

Comment: Be used at the same time your two macros so become grammar violation, it is not possible.

Comment: use GCC extension : `#define MY_SIZE_OF(x) ({ typeof(x) v; (char*)(&v + 1) - (char*)(&v);})`

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that.  Part of the evil magic that is preprocessor macros is that it is a simple text replacement with no judgment of syntactic context.  This is so that you can do all sorts of wacky stuff like concatenating symbols, lazy evaluations, etc. etc.  The other end of that is that you can't turn around and ask it what its parameter is - it's all just text in a macro.

Short of declaring a macro for *every symbol in your source*, including both types and variables, that consists of the symbol concatenated with `__MY_SIZE` or something, you really can't do this.  You are stuck with a `sizeof` you didn't write, for better or worse.